# magento 1.7 - API - determine if detail is simple, bundle, or component of bundle

Tags: api, magento-1.7

I am extracting new orders in Magento using API. I would like to know how I can tell if this is a simple product, bundle or component of a bundle.

To get details I use soapObject method for 'sales_order.info'

```
$details = $this->soapObject->call($this->sessionId, 'sales_order.info', $orderId);
```

when I dump details, it looks like this:

```
array(15) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(3) "232"
  ["weight"]=>
  string(6) "1.0000"
  ["sku"]=>
  string(12) "BD22"
  ["name"]=>
  string(28) "BUNDLED_PRODUCT22"
  ["qty_ordered"]=>
  string(6) "2.0000"
  ["price"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_percent"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_discount_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["tax_percent"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["row_weight"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["price_incl_tax"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another SOAP service [`catalog_product.info`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html).

Assuming `product_id`* is a Magento product entity id, pass it to a `catalog_product.info` SOAP call to get the product details.

The response will contain a field named `type`, which contains the product type.

---

*<sub>Afaik `it_product_id` is no original Magento field. Looks like you're using some 3rd party module which overrides the Magento API.</sub>

Comment: Brillant!  I was looking in wrong place.  BTW it_ prefix was probably in house thing. I removed from my post.